# Generic types in annotations

Tags: java, generics, annotations

Consider the following code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @GenericAnnotation<String>(foo = "Test")
    public class Bar1 {

    }

    @ObjectAnnotation(foo = "Test")
    public class Bar2 {

    }

    @WorkingAnnotation(foo = "Test")
    public class Bar3 {

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface GenericAnnotation<T> {

        public T foo();

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface ObjectAnnotation {

        public Object foo();

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface WorkingAnnotation {

        public String foo();

    }

}
```

`Bar1` won't compile at all. Huge mess of errors.

`Bar2` will compile fine, but the `ObjectAnnotation` annotation won't.

`Bar3` will compile fine, but doesn't allow generic types.

---

If - for example - I am trying to set a default value in case a certain field can't be loaded. This class might be an `Integer`, `String`, `Boolean[]`, really any of the possible types. This means a whole mess of annotations for handling every possibly case.

---

Is there a proper way to handle generic types in an annotation? If not, is there a clear reason why?

Comment: I know it has been a long time since the question has been asked, but could the answer be accepted?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler's error messages are confusing purely because it is not laid out to accept such a syntax.

A similar question was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594582/annotation-attributes-with-type-parameters/7602554#7602554).

## Case 1

The JLS, [Section 9.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) states the general syntax of an annotation declaration as follows:

> AnnotationTypeDeclaration:
>
> ```
> {InterfaceModifier} @ interface Identifier AnnotationTypeBody
> ```

The token *Identifier*, in the terms of the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), describes the name of the type; be it class, enum, interface or annotation.

An annotation can not be declared with generic types, as these are referred to by the token [TypeParameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), which is not included here.

As to why, this leads to

## Case 2

Looking into the next item, [Section 9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1), we spot the restriction of types an annotation can take:

> The return type of a method declared in an annotation type must be one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - A primitive type
> - String
> - Class or an invocation of Class (§[4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5))
> - An enum type
> - An annotation type
> - An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types (§[10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)).

(some special cases are addressed further below, but are irrelevant to this problem)

These restrictions are what's causing the dejection of your second annotation. It is simply not designed to hold all types of Objects. It cannot even hold the boxed type of a primitive!

Now, back to **Case 1** for a bit: Why are generic Annotations a wrong thing in this grammar? Even before any type erasure occurs, your GenericAnnotation can basically be a holder for every type of Object. It is, in the definition of its *foo* property, exactly the same as your *ObjectAnnotation*.

Now, the question is, why is that limitation in place? By limiting the values an annotation might contain, you get two advantages: First, all the values are to be compile-time constants. There is no way to get a runtime-dependent value either into or out of an annotation without heavy use of reflection.

This immediately brings one to the second advantage: Nobody will even get the temptation to put impure (side-effecting) code inside annotations which may be loaded at any random point in the applications lifetime. If you could introduce any type of object, their constructors could do any kind of side-effect at a possibly undetectable time, increasing the complexity of debugging if this technique were used.

Or at least, that's what seems the most logical to me, as there is no official word on this from either Sun or their successors that I could find.

## Possible Workaround: None

There is, sadly, no simple, expressive and easy workaround to this.
As you cannot place processes into @Annotation-uses, you can not even do something fancy as serializing the object into a byte array using ObjectOutputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: Good point about case 2. I think we could go even further: Annotations might be loaded at times when the VM is not even in "executing ready" state or (when thinking about restrictive classloaders), such code would probably be executed in a very privileged and unprotected context of the VM. Or, you can load a class just for parsing annotations, without instanciating anything. Also there it's not expected that the analyzed (potentially harmful) code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Not having generic annotations is sadly a limitation of the framework. One solution is to have a field describing the desired class and checking/casting types at runtime.