# Getting the .class of a parameterised type?

Tags: java, generics

If a List  and want to get the class of that rather than List, 
I cant't do

```
List.class
```

I can't do

```
List<TennisBall>.class
```

The reason I want to do this is I am using an annotation which excepts Class which generates documentation.  I can express the parameterised class.

Any tips

Comment: you can't do `List<TennisBall>.class` because of type erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html
.This is probably also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641047/generic-types-in-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that generics are 99% a compile-time construct. Generics don't create new classes/interfaces. Both `List` (the raw type) and `List<TennisBall>` (the parameterized type) are represented by the same class, which is `List.class`. (And the implementation of a class is similarly shared: `LinkedList` and `LinkedList<TennisBall>` are both implemented by the same class.)

You'll need to refer to the annotation's documentation to see what to do about generics with that tool when what you want it to document involves a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Generics ensure typesafety at compile-time, but were also designed to avoid overhead at runtime. Therefore the Java compiler applies "type erasure" - which means that information about generics is not written into the .class files.

I can recommend to read this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) from Baeldung.