# Java - Why is Enum<E> not allowed as Annotation member?

Tags: java, generics, enums, annotations

It says:

> primitive
>
> String
>
> Class
>
> an Enum
>
> another Annotation
>
> an array of any of the above

Only these types are legal to be as Annotation member, why can't a generic Enum be a member of Annotation?

For example :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Param {

    Enum value();

}
```

This is not allowed. But Enum is a constant isn't it? As you are using `@Param(XXX)`, filling in the `Enum`, the `@Param(XXX)` is decided (which means this is constant). Why is it only a specific enum allowed to be a member?

What I am trying to do is to make a Annotation that receives any enums:

```
// for example
@Param(value = AEnum.ABC)
@Param(value = BEnum.TTT)
@Param(value = CEnum.OOO)
```

I want all above to be legal.

Comment: I think because Enum and Enum<E> are different types.

Comment: That's just language design, you just cannot.

Comment: @Jesper: that doesn’t look like a duplicate. The other question is about **Class** values which just happen to be a `Class<? extends Enum>`, but that’s just coincidence. The other question would work for any other `Class<? extends Foo>` as well, whereas this question is about `enum` *instances* as annotation values.

Comment: @Holger that other question (that I asked myself, btw) is not just about `Class` values, it's about annotation properties with type parameters in general, which is the same question as is asked here. (Whether the parameterized type is `Class` or `Enum` or something else isn't relevant). Apparently the answer is: this is not allowed because it would lead to a lot of complexity that the Java language designers were not willing to take.

Comment: @Jesper: but this question isn’t asking for type parameters at all.

Comment: @Holger Ok, I see... I've reopened it. Still the other question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594582/annotation-attributes-with-type-parameters

Answer (score 1):

While each `enum` type inherits from `java.lang.Enum`, the type `Enum` itself is not an `enum` type. Similarly, while every annotation type inherits from `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`, the type `Annotation` itself is not an annotation type.

There is no technical reason for this, in the class file, each actual value will contain a reference to its type. So it would be technical possible to declare an annotation attribute as `Object` and discover the types of the actual values dynamically, but that’s not allowed by the formal specification.

By the way, enum constants also are not compile-time constants. So while you can declare a compile-time constant like `final String FOO = "some string";` and refer to it in an annotation like `@Name(value=FOO)`, you can’t do the same with an `enum` constant. You can only refer to the constant as declared in the `enum` type itself like `EnumType.NAME`. This also is a consequence of how it is formally defined in the specification.